Unable to add New Test in Android Studio
I am using AS Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2 on mac OS.
To add New Test for a class, it's usually using Command+Shift+T when the cursor was put in the class or a function/method. But "No Test subjects found" tooltip shows up. And from menu (File) or RMB there is no were shows New Test.
